# How to grab data from fields in the model and populate them to a django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm currently constructing a create layout page for users to input values and use within a template. My problem right now is in my view function I can't get the field data out of the model and repopulate it into a django form. I want only 1 data entry for the Layout model that is always grabbed and put into the form so the user can edit then resave it. This issue will reside in the View.py. Here is what i have:

***View.py:***

```
def create_layoutform(request, template_name='layout/create.html'):
    if len(Layout.objects.all()) > 0:
        # if you have a form, load it
        MyLayout = Layout.objects.get(pk=1)
        LayoutUpdateForm = LayoutForm(MyLayout)    

        tmpl_vars = {
            'layoutupdateform':LayoutUpdateForm,
        }
        return render(request, template_name, tmpl_vars)
    else:
        layout_form = LayoutForm(request.POST or None)
        layout = layout_form.save(commit=False)
        layout.save()
        tmpl_vars = {
            'layoutform':layout_form,
        }
        return render(request, template_name, tmpl_vars)
```

**My print output for the view: Layout.objects.get(pk=1)**

**Grabs just the name of the model (Layout object)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because of this line; `LayoutUpdateForm = LayoutForm(MyLayout)`. The first argument to a Django Form is `data`, but you want to use the `instance` arguments [1]. Try changing it to `LayoutUpdateForm = LayoutForm(instance=MyLayout)`.

NOTE: This assumes your `LayoutForm` is inherited from `forms.ModelForm`.

[1] https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L313

Comment: `The first argument to a Django Form is data, but you want to use the instance arguments [1].` Got it to work now, Thank you.